# Freezing of Columns in sap.ui.table

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a sap.ui.table which has many columns.
The first two columns are fixed and should be displayed even when scrolling. The other columns can be scrolled in and out of view.
I have used the `enableColumnFreeze: true` property but it's default value is false and I have to click on the column and hit the freeze button for the property to work.
Even then the property works for all the columns i.e. I can hit the freeze button for every column.
Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the table's `fixedColumnCount` property to 2. [From the API](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.table.Table.html#getFixedColumnCount):

> Number of columns that are fix on the left. When you use a horizontal
>   scroll bar, only the columns which are not fixed, will scroll. Fixed
>   columns need a defined width for the feature to work

Comment: Missed that one. Propably the better solution.

Comment: Thank you Qualiture, this worked like a charm. No need to use enableColumnFreeze also.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to [fire this event](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.table.Table.html#event:columnFreeze) for the columns you want to freeze. Don't know if that works without generally allowing column freeze.

**Edit:** Untested and incomplete code example:

```
var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table();
var oColumn1 = new sap.ui.table.Column();
var oColumn2 = new sap.ui.table.Column();
oTable.addColumn(oColumn1);
oTable.addColumn(oColumn2);
oTable.fireColumnFreeze({column : oColumn1});
```

Comment: I am new to sapui5 could you tell me how to fire the event. Help would be greatly appreciated.